# Question about accumulated values and nominal rates of discount

Tags: finance, actuarial-science, compound-interest

A collection agency pays a doctor $\$5,000$ for invoices that the doctor hasn't been able to collect on. After two years, the collection agency has collected $\$6,000$ on the invoices. At what nominal rate of discount compounded monthly did the agency receive on this transaction?

I'm trying to use the following relationship:
$$a(t) = (1 + i^m/m)^{mt}$$

using the following values

$$6000 = (1 + i^{12}/12)^{12\times 2}$$

when I solved for $i^{12}$ I got the following
$$ (6000^{1/24}-1)\times 12 = i^{12}$$

However this can't be the correct answer. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In your computation, you appear to have lost the $5,000$ the doctor eventually received.

Comment: Should say:  I reformatted your post, largely to handle the dollar signs (which can't easily be used as such in the formatting system)...I tried to leave your formulas the same, but I don't understand your formula for monthly compounding.  Normally, I'd expect a term like $\frac r{12}$ but you seem to be exponentiating twice.

Comment: @lulu Since 6000 is the accumulated value isn't that the only value that should be used? In the formula, m = 12 and the time period is over two years. So it would be compounding monthly for 24 months.

Comment: I don't understand.  Think of it as a (bad) investment.  The doctor has an asset worth $6000$ but after two years it is only worth $5000$.  Thus the investment has lost money.  Your job is to compute the discount factor that would explain that drop.  And, as I say, your formula for monthly compounding is wrong.

Comment: Ah, the problem is phrased from the collection agency's viewpoint (not the doctor's).  Thus, reverse the numbers.  They invested $5000$ and got $6000$ in the end, so they had a positive return.

Comment: @j.jerrod.taylor Probably the equation is $$6000 = 5000\cdot (1 + i_{12})^{12\times 2},$$ where $i_{12}$ is the monthly nominal rate of discount.

Comment: @callculus42 I'll try that.

Comment: In callculus42's formula (which is otherwise correct), $i_{12}$ should be $\frac{i}{12}$.